# How can I insulate the door to my attic?

Tags: insulation, attic

I have a 5 level townhouse; heat seems to come out of the area around the door to the attic in warm days. is it possible to add insulation to this attic and door? the attic is walkable and has plywood floors so I'm not sure if i can lay insulation down and walk on it or what other options i have. the attic is pretty warm but ventilated appropriately. any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Editing this post (click the word "edit" just below your text) to add pictures would be very helpful. If you have difficulty doing that directly, load them to imgur and edit to post the link, and someone will edit them in for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if there's a lack of insulation under the plywood floors, taking up the plywood, insulating, and replacing the plywood would be the correct method.

If there's insulation there but it's inadequate, that's a different issue.

Hard to know about door insulation without any idea what sort of door you have. If it's a trap door you can probably put some insulation over the top of it in some way, but the way will depend on how it opens/operates.

Comment: the door is a regular door. i measure it yesterday and was thinking about getting a big sheet of foam and stapling/nailing it to the door, trying to add some overlap so that air does not come into the living space.